# RuntimeError: Model class django_celery_beat.models.SolarSchedule doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat, django-celery-beat

I'm using my virtualenv and upon executing `celery -A app beat -l info -S django`, this error always displays.
`RuntimeError: Model class django_celery_beat.models.SolarSchedule doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

N.B: `django_celery_beat` already installed and migrated.

I have used the following versions, like

1. Python Version: 3.8
2. Celery Version: 5.1.1
3. Celery-Beat Version: 2.2.1

But my expectation is to run celery smoothly :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add `django_celery_beat` to INSTALLED_APPS in your Apps settings.py file.

Comment: N.B: django_celery_beat already installed and migrated.